# Show that $|z+1|\le|z+1|^2 +|z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Question: Show that $|z+1|\le|z+1|^2 +|z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

So far I have,

Suppose  $1\le|z+1|$

$|z+1|\le|z+1|^2$

$|z+1|\le|z+1|^2+|z|$

Now I must show $|z+1|<1$ but this is where I'm stuck

Comment: You should be stuck. What if $z=2$?

Comment: I think it's badly written : "If $1\leqslant |z+1|$, then $|z+1|\leqslant|z+1|^2$ hence $|z+1|\leqslant |z+1|^2+|z|$, now I must show that the inequality is also true when $|z+1|<1$, but this is where I'm stuck."

Comment: Note that for $z = a+ib \in \mathbb C$, $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot, i edited it. i mistakenly typed my side step in the problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok but its a complex numbers question so you should try to understand it in those terms.
You have a triangle with vertices the origin, $-1$ and $z$. The side lengths are 
$1$, $|z|$, and $|z+1|$
so we have 
$$1 \leq |z+1|+|z|$$ in addition 
$$2|z+1|\leq |z+1|^2 +1$$
 adding we get 
$$2|z+1|+1\leq |z+1|^2 +1+|z+1|+|z|$$

which gives 
$$|z+1|\leq |z+1|^2 +|z|$$

(the second inequality follows from ($0 \leq (|z+1|-1)^2$)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a 'less complex' approach:

First, let $w=z+1$, then we want to prove $|w| \le |w|^2+ |w-1|$.

Now let $w=r e^{i \theta}$, and note that $|w-1| = \sqrt{r^2+1-2 r \cos \theta} \ge |1-r|$.

Since $|w| = r$, if we can show $r \le r^2 + |1-r|$, then we are finished.

If $r \ge 1$ this is clearly true because $r^2 \ge r$.

If $r <1$, we have $0 \le r^2 -2r +1 = (r-1)^2$ which is clearly true.

Comment: It is not simpler and it has a case analysis.

Comment: Well, it focuses on properties of the reals rather than complex numbers, so it is 'less complex' as such. I interpret 'less complex' as simpler :-).

Comment: Oh, I see, what you mean, but I think these questions are best approached by emphasising the complex nature, so for me a more complex solution is better.

Comment: @copper.hat the question specifically states, when z is an element of Complex

Comment: Just to be clear Coppers solution is valid for all complex numbers.

Comment: @copper.hat Its just that your approach is different than what I was thinking, I didnt mean anything by it

Comment: Where did you come up with $\sqrt {r^2+1-2r\cos\theta} \ge |1-r|$?

Comment: @dfeuer: $-1 \le \cos \theta \le +1$.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is similar to that of Rene Schipperus, but approaches the problem from a slightly different direction.

We wish to prove that $|z+1| \le |z+1|^2 + |z|$.

Subtracting both sides of the inequality by $|z|$ and multiplying by $|z+1|+|z|$ yields

$$|z+1|^2 - |z|^2 \stackrel?\le |z+1|^2 (|z+1|+|z|)$$

There's just one slightly awkward term here, the $-|z|^2$, so let's isolate that on one side and see what we get:

$$-|z|^2 \stackrel?\le |z+1|^2(|z+1|+|z|-1).$$

Now look at the term $|z+1|+|z|$: that's the sum of the distance between $z$ and $-1$ and the distance between $z$ and $0$. By the triangle inequality, $|z+1| + |z| \ge |-1 - 0| = 1$. Thus the term $|z+1|+|z|-1$ is at least $0$. Multiplying by $|z+1|^2$ doesn't change that, so $$-|z|^2 \le 0 \le |z+1|^2 (|z+1|+|z|-1).$$
All the steps above are reversible (note in particular that dividing by $|z+1|+|z|$ is permissible because we have shown it is strictly greater than $0$).

#### Note

If you're wondering how I decided to subtract by $|z|$ and multiply by $|z+1|^2 + |z|$, well … I can't quite tell that whole story. I was generally thinking that it's easier to think about *squares* of complex magnitudes than about the magnitudes themselves, and producing a difference of squares sometimes makes square things without making too many non-square things. The fact that it led to something useful seems to be more luck than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

From the triangle inequality,

$$
\begin{align}
|z| + |z+1|^2 - |z+1| &= |z| + |z+1| - 1 + (|z+1|-1)^2 \\
&\geq |1+z-z| - 1 + (|z+1|-1)^2 \\
&= (|z+1|-1)^2 \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is essentially the same as Rene's answer, though without the nice geometric interpretation.

Comment: Most elegant answer so far